# Exclude current page from WP loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I've built a navigation using simple HTML and Php. It's straightforward, but I'd like it to either:

1. exclude the current post from the loop so it doesn't appear or
2. have some sort of identifying style change to show it's the current page.

There's a couple of pages out there, but nothing I've tried is working out. Anybody have any ideas?

Code:

```html
<div class="project-nav" style="display:none;">
 <div class="nav-container"> 

  <?php
  $catPost = get_posts('cat=5&posts_per_page=-1000');
  foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="nav-fixed">
     <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
    </div>
   </a>

  <?php  endforeach;?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain what it's doing verses what you want it to do?

Comment: When I use this, it shows all posts from the category I selected. I'd like it to show all of them, minus the one the user is currently viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="project-nav" style="display:none;">
    <div class="nav-container"> 

    <?php
    $current_id =  get_the_ID();
    $catPost = get_posts('cat=5&posts_per_page=-1000');

    foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
        if ( get_the_ID() == $current_id ) {
            continue;
        }

    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="nav-fixed">
                <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>

            </div>
    </a>

    <?php  endforeach;?>

</div>
```

Comment: No dice - now the text is displaying as a series of numbers:
"
1036103610281004943109098211021067975858812
"
Tried messing around with it, but got Php errors. Any other ideas/iterations?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for your help!